# Как правильно запускать несколько таймеров?

Tags: java

Как правильно создавать несколько таймеров с различными задачами?

Я создавал так:

```
    private Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");

    public void start(){
        long delay1 = 1000L;
        long period1 = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L;
        long period2 = 60000L;

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskRecruit, delay1 , period1);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskHoliday,delay2, period2);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskTraining, delay3, period3);
    }

    private TimerTask taskRecruit = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    private TimerTask taskHoliday= new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    private TimerTask taskTraining = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };
```

Но я уверен, что я не правильно реализую мультитаскинг. Как правильно должно быть записано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, могу предложить заюзать `ExecutorService`.

В качестве преимуществ:

1. Можно подсунуть любую функцию вместо TimerTask-ов с переопределенными методами
2. Выбор TimeUnit-a. Если удобнее, к примеру, в минутах указать время, то зачем себе отказывать

Пример

```
public void start(){
    Task task = new Task();
    long delay1 = 1000, delay2 = 2, delay3 = 1, period1 = 2000, period2 = 3, period3 = 1;
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Task::taskRecruit, delay1, period1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task::taskHoliday, delay2, period2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("lambda"), delay3, period3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
...
class Task{
    void taskHoliday() {
        System.out.println("method");
    }
    static void taskRecruit() {
        System.out.println("static");
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, по подробнее расписать привести ваш пример кода. Хотя бы с демо-примером вывода на экрана "Hello World!" и "This works!"

Comment: @Antonio112009 Добавил пример

Comment: Хороший один из вариантов. Проверил - вроде рабочий)) Сам таймер работает

Comment: Кстати, что значат двоеточия в записи `Task::taskRecruit`??

Comment: @Antonio112009 Ссылка на метод. В языке появился с 8 версии. `Task::taskRecruit` - это ссылка на метод `taskRecruit` из класса `Task` (т.к. он статический, мы можем к нему так обращаться). `taskHoliday` - нестатический метод. По-этому, к нему обратиться можем через объект. `task::taskHoliday` - ссылка на метод `taskHoliday` объекта `task`. Думаю, больше вопросов тут возникнуть не должно

Comment: Да вопросов вообще не было к Task и task) Я просто двоеточий еще не встречал

Comment: спасибо, что показали такой необычный способ вызова методов

Comment: @Antonio112009, уже достаточно обычный :) Я просто хотел показать все основные варианты