# java как сделать таймер

Tags: java

Я хотел бы чтоб проще говоря у меня был таймер который после 1 минуты выполнял часть кода , допустим прибавлял к одной переменной еще 5 , и после этой минуты начал повторять это дело заново .
В заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный ответ с использованием `Timer` тебе подойдет, но я бы порекомендовал бы использовать `ExecutorService`.

Вот как он используется:

```
public void start(){
    Task task = new Task();
    long delay1 = 1000, delay2 = 2, delay3 = 1, period1 = 2000, period2 = 3, period3 = 1;
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Task::taskRecruit, delay1, period1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task::taskHoliday, delay2, period2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("lambda"), delay3, period3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
...
class Task{
    void taskHoliday() {
        System.out.println("method");
    }
    static void taskRecruit() {
        System.out.println("static");
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на оригинал ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918966/275232)

Преимущества использования `ExecutorService` вместо `Timer`:

**Ответ 1** ([Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409993/8992586)):

> По мнению автора книги [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/):
>
> - `Timer` может быть чувствительным к изменениям системных часов, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` - нет.
> - `Timer` имеет только **один поток выполнения**, поэтому **длительное выполнение задачи может задержать выполнение других задач**. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` может быть настроен с **любым
>     количеством потоков**. Кроме того, вы можете полностью контролировать
>     созданные потоки, если хотите (используя `ThreadFactory`).
> - Ошибки (Exeptions), вызванные во время выполнения TimerTask, уничтожают **единственный** поток, что делает Timer мертвым :-( ...
>     т.е. запланированные задачи больше не будут выполняться.
>     `ScheduledThreadExecutor` не только перехватывает ошибки (Exceptions)
>     во время выполнения, но и позволяет вам обрабатывать их, если хотите
>     (переопределяя метод `afterExecute` из `ThreadPoolExecutor`). Задача,
>     вызвавшая исключение, будет отменена, но другие задачи продолжат
>     выполняться.

**Ответ 2** ([Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317753/8992586)):

> Из официальной документации Oracle на их странице о
>   [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):
>
> > `ThreadPoolExecutor`, который может дополнительно запланировать
> >     выполнение команд после заданной задержки или периодическое
> >     выполнение. Этот класс предпочтительнее, чем `Timer`, когда требуется
> >     несколько рабочих потоков или когда требуется дополнительная гибкость
> >     или возможности `ThreadPoolExecutor` (который расширяет этот класс).
>
> `ExecutorService/ThreadPoolExecutor` или `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`
>   это конечно же лучший выбор при работе с многопоточностью.
>
> Плюсы `ExecutorService` перед `Timer`:
>
> 1. `Timer` не может использовать преимущества доступных процессорных
>      ядер в отличие от `ExecutorService`, особенно с несколькими задачами,
>      использующими разновидности `ExecutorService`, такие как [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)
> 2. `ExecutorService` предоставляет совместный API, если вам нужна координация между несколькими задачами. Предположим, что вам
>      необходимо отправить N рабочих задач и дождаться завершения всех из
>      них. Вы можете легко достичь этого с помощью [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) API.
>      Если вы хотите добиться того же с несколькими задачами таймера, это
>      было бы не просто.
> 3. [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) предоставляет лучший API для управления жизненным циклом потока.

[Ссылка на оригинал вопроса/ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

Comment: прошу простить но я  еще не проверил ваш ответ на практике завтра проверю и там уже поставлю галочку .

Answer (score 3):

**@since 1.3** есть `java.util.Timer`

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task : " + new Date());
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");

long delay = 1000L;
timer.schedule(task, delay);
```

вышеприведенный код, в секции `TimerTask.run()` выполнится 1 раз через 1000мс

Если вам надо повторяющееся действие, с постоянной **задержкой**, необходимо у таймера вызывать

```
long peroid = 1000L;
timer.schedule (task, delay, peroid);
```

Если вам надо повторяющееся действие, с постоянной **частотой**, то для этого существует метод

```
long peroid = 1000L;
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate (task, delay, peroid);
```

Если Вам нужен таймер в **Swing GUI** потоке, то на этот случай тоже есть специальный класс javax.swing.Timer

```
int delay = 1000;
ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("task : " + new Date());
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, listener);
timer.start();
```

Чтобы операция повторялась необходимо добавить

```
timer.setRepeats(true);
```

**@since 1.5** появился `ScheduledExecutorService` из пакета `java.util.concurrent`, который так же предназначен для выполнения периодических задач, но уже в многопоточной среде, он так же отлично подойдет для одного потока:

```
int corePoolSize = 1;
int delay = 1;
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize);
service.schedule(() -> System.out.println("task : " + new Date()), delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: почему то delay в случаях с частотой и задержкой становиться ошибкой

Comment: TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("task : " + new Date());
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
        long peroid = 1000L;
        timer.schedule (task, delay, peroid);