# Остановка и запуск Timer

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-timer, java-timertask

У меня есть класс, в котором есть методы, запускающие и останавливающие таймер.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest {
    private Timer wrkTimer = new Timer(true);

    public void StartWork() {
        TimerTask wrkTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("I'm working.");
            }
        };

        wrkTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(wrkTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void StopWork() {
        wrkTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

В `main` я создаю второй таймер, который сначала останавливает, потом запускает заново таймер в `TimerTest`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer wrkTimer1 = new Timer("timer1", true);
        TimerTest tt = new TimerTest();

        tt.StartWork();

        TimerTask wrkTask1 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tt.StopWork();
                tt.StartWork();
            }
        };

        wrkTimer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(wrkTask1, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

При выполнении выдается исключение `Exception in thread "timer1" 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.`

Как я понял, исключение вызывается тем, что при остановке таймера из `TimerTest` через `cancel()` и при последующем запуске нужно заново создавать `TimerTask`, но разве в методе `StartWork()` `TimerTask` не создается заново?

```
TimerTask wrkTask = new TimerTask() {...};
```

Есть ли варианты как обойти данную проблему не меняя архитектуры программы? Или дело вообще не в `TimerTask`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446083/216510

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать `Timer`. Объяснение найдешь [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice), пример использования `executerService` - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/948889/275232) и в гуле

Comment: + Можешь описать что делают по сути твои таймеры? Может я смогу по другому реализовать твою идею

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, зачем вы создаёте `daemon` потоки, если по идее должны создавать `user` потоки? Советую прочитать вам [вот эту статью](https://www.baeldung.com/java-daemon-thread).
Во-вторых, вы пересоздаёте `wrkTask`, но не пересоздаёте `wrkTimer`, из-за чего и вылетает исключение.
В-третьих, вам не нужно пересоздавать `wrkTask`, потому что это не имеет смысла.

Вот так должен выглядеть метод `StopWorking()`:

```java
public void StopWorking() {
    wrkTimer.cancel();
    wrkTimer = new Timer();
}
```